# The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic module

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I get the error when I run this code:

```
  var asmName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly");
  var asmBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly
      (asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
  var moduleBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule");
  var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("DynamicType", TypeAttributes.Public);
  var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("DynamicMethod", MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(double), new[] { typeof(double), typeof(double), typeof(double) });
  myexp.Lambda.CompileToMethod(methodBuilder);
  asmBuilder.SetEntryPoint(methodBuilder);

  MethodInfo barMethod = asmBuilder.EntryPoint;
  result = barMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { 50d, 1d, 3d });
```

I get the error on the last line

> The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic module.

I just want to call the method.

I added

```
  <runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
```

to my `app.config` to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide `myexp` or a stripped down version of it to make your snipped compileable?

Comment: shouldn't you put typeBuilder .CreateType() somewhere?

Comment: @RegisPortalez, I tried that first, actually. The type from `.Createtype()` does not have that method in it's `Members` collection.

Comment: @toddmo from the msdn entry of `TypeBuilder`: `Before a type is used, the TypeBuilder.CreateType method must be called.` So there is no way around this call. If you get unexcepted results, something other seems to be wrong.

Comment: @thehennyy, ok I'll keep my code as is but add that line and see what happens

Answer (score 4):

As @thehennyy pointed out in comment you should call `typeBuilder.CreateType()` before invoking method, but calling `Invoke` from `methodBuilder` cause same error.

I've managed to call method after getting it from created type like this:

```
var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
var method = type.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Here is complete code that I've used:

```
Expression<Func<double, double, double, double>> myexp = (a, b, c) => a * b * c;
var methodName = "DynamicMethod";

var asmName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly");
var asmBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var moduleBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule");
var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("DynamicType", TypeAttributes.Public);
var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(methodName, MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(double), new[] { typeof(double), typeof(double), typeof(double) });

myexp.CompileToMethod(methodBuilder);
var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
var method = type.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

asmBuilder.SetEntryPoint(method);
MethodInfo barMethod = asmBuilder.EntryPoint;
var result = barMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { 50d, 1d, 3d });
```